# Run a function if loop executed

Tags: python, python-3.x

How would you write this code elegantly?

```py
for i in get_generator():
    # ...

# if loop executed then call the function
some_function()
```

Comment: Just like you did... what was the problem with it?

Comment: @mkrieger1 `for i ...` might not execute then I don't want to run the function

Comment: @mkrieger1 I think what the OP meant was how would he 'elegantly' check if the ```for loop``` actually ran and if so, run ```some_function()```.

Comment: What do you mean by "might not execute"? If you write it, it will execute.

Comment: The question seems to be whether the generator yielded at least one item and thus the loop body has executed at least once.

Answer (score 2):

If your problem is to detect if there were any items returned by the generator (did the body of the loop execute at least once):

```py
loop_executed = False
for i in get_generator():
    loop_executed = True
    # ...

if loop_executed:
    some_function()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
loop_executed = False
for i in get_generator():
  loop_executed = True
  # ...
    
# if loop executed, then call the function
if loop_executed:
  some_function()
```

Alternatively, if this get_generator call is not dynamic and does not change its state you can also just do something like

```
for i in get_generator():
    # ...

# if loop executed, then call the function
if get_generator() is not None: # or empty or whatever
    some_function()
```